# Run tests one at a time (order is not important)

Tags: unit-testing, xunit

How do I make the xunit test runner run tests one at a time for a specific class?

The order is not important (all tests change the current culture)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only simple solution is to use `tearDown` method to reset back the culture.

The current culture is a global variable, global variables are always an issue for unit testing. So you need to restart VM to reset it back to a default value for each test. Though it's not necessary, because it is thread local, and if you could force test framework to span new a thread for each unit test, it could work too. But it is all black magic and it makes unit tests heavier.

As alternative, you could refactor your code to inject a current culture holder. In this case you could mock culture holder in your unit tests and pass a simple implementation to hold culture in the global variable.